# Fragment as Serializable Bundle Extra

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an `ArrayList` of `Fragment`s being utilized in a FragmentPagerAdapter.

I want to save the state of this `ArrayList` in the `saveState()` and restore it within a `restoreState(...)` method. Can a `Fragment` be stored with a bundle?

I am doing so via

```
bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable(REGISTERED_FRAGMENTS_BUNDLE, registeredFragments);
```

and retreiving like

```
@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    if (state != null) {
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
        bundle.setClassLoader(loader);
        ArrayList<Fragment> savedFragments = (ArrayList<Fragment>) bundle.getSerializable(REGISTERED_FRAGMENTS_BUNDLE);
.
.
```

I am getting an "Unable to marshal value" error when this code is run. Is what I am trying even possible? What would be a feasible alternative?

Thanks,
Otterman

Comment: Did you add `implements Serializable` to the fragment?

Answer (score 3):

Fragment cant be Serializable , u should just keep simple data in bundle and refresh the views and fragments in restoreState method using bundle.